# Host will not allow Mysql Sub Queries, Can this be done any other way?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM `finishes` Order by `finish`, `fdate` DESC) AS `output`
GROUP BY `finish`
```

The above works perfectly on my localhost machine, but on uploading it to my Servage hosting (naming and shaming!) it falls over and throws out a syntax error, when i asked Servage why this was and whether support for subqueries could be enabled, they flatly refused saying its not supported on their servers! (poor customer service as usual, which ive come to expect from them.)

Anyhow.. is there any way to rewrite the above without sub queries, all i want to do is get the latest entry in the table , grouped by finish , but it needs to show other data that belongs to that row. I tried max (fdate), and although this pulled the right date, it still showed data in other columns from the first entry in the database, not the last.

Scratching my head on this one.

Paul

Comment: Something is *fishy* here ...

Comment: Well if it throws out a syntax error, how about checking the..syntax? Like the space between first FROM and first parenthesis ?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Ive put it on a fiddle, here--> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c1cd/3/0

Answer (score 0):

It may work perfectly for you now, but it may not always work perfectly. (MySQL allows you to use a GROUP BY clause like this, but does not guarantee which values for the other fields will be returned)

Try this

```
SELECT `finishes`.*
FROM `finishes`
JOIN (SELECT `finish`, MAX(fdate) as `latest`
      FROM `finishes`
      GROUP BY `finish`) AS T1
  ON T1.`finish` = `finishes`.`finish`
   AND T1.`latest` = `finishes`.`fdate`
```

Comment: Instead of marking me down (those who have) , why dont you read the question fully, as i stated the problem is not the syntax, its the fact the host DOES NOT allow subqueries.. @Agrizzo is a Join classed as a non Subquery? as if it is a subquery, they will not allow it to run

Comment: That again will run on my localhost, but not on the LIVE server hosted by Servage.. so i guess that answers the question on whether or not that is classed as a Subquery.. Thats for the help though :)

Comment: @Paul501 - You could run the subquery standalone then use the results from your scripting language (php?) to then find the detail (Horrible performance). Another option would be to build a table to hold the results of the subquery, then use that table as the join table. (I'm not sure how realtime your data needs to be, but you could schedule that table to be rebuilt every so often).  Finally I doubt this would work (but since I have no idea how they were able to stop MySQL from processing a subquery), could you make a view out of the subquery and use that view as the join?

Comment: Thats all abit beyond my scope, but thanks for the reply, ive just had to rethink how im going to present the data, and do it completely differently, i did put a fiddle up above, showing it does work, but just not on the server.. ah well.. next time i`ll choose a better host.